# Python sort 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in python 3.6.5 which goes as follows

```
a_list = [['name1', 5, 6, 3, 7], ['name3', 2, 6, 3, 6], ['name3', 2, 10, 8, 5]]
```

So it's basically name, score1, score2 etc.

I want to add up the scores and rank they names highest to lowest

So far, I have

```
a_list.sort(a_list, key=lambda x: x[not sure what to put here], reverse=True)
```

I need a way of adding up the numbers in the list without affecting the str field.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you meant to have duplicate names?

Comment: how does the desired output look like for the example you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
a_list = [['name1', 5, 6, 3, 7], ['name3', 2, 6, 3, 6], ['name3', 2, 10, 8, 5]]
a_list.sort(key=lambda x: sum(x[1:]), reverse=True)
print(a_list)
```

Output:

```
[['name3', 2, 10, 8, 5], ['name1', 5, 6, 3, 7], ['name3', 2, 6, 3, 6]]
```